# Newbie - adb_vendor_keys issue on dji android device

Tags: android, adb

Been browsing this group, found some great answers on here, but none have helped me with my problem.

We have a new ( less than 1 month old) dji device, called a smart controller, it’s basically an android tablet, it’s built into our drone remote controller.

A few days ago it came up wirh an error message duijg @ Flight, which was basically a memory overflow.

So we suspect the internal memory has been filled by the local cache files.

The issue is that this has now stopped the device even starting up.

We have tried installing drivers on our pc, including the firmware update application from dji, but this just fails every time we try it.

Today we have been following advice on here, and using Rhe ADB program on our pc, we do at least get a connection to the device.

However we can’t do anything withnht program.

Each time we try any command we get this message

Device unauthorised 
This adb server $adb_vendor_keys is not set.

We have tried deleting the public key, on the pc, and creating a new one, but we can’t write that new key to the device.

We are not programmers and don’t know code, so we are doing all this on our pc in a command line prompt.

Before we give up and send it back to China, anyone got any ideas on what we might be able to do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without being able the use the physical device. I do not believe there is anything that you can do. Generally speaking the error you are seeing is caused due to a permission prompt that would appear on the device authorizing your computer to interact with it.

If you could get the device to display and disable and re-enable usb debugging a security prompt should display when you connect it to your PC. Without that option I would recommend sending it back

Comment: Thanks for the comment!,yep we felt the same too, so it was decided the device was beyond economic repair,,and was sent back to dji.com for further investigation. Thanks for the response again.